# Неверная контрольная подпись Python

Tags: python, api

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Недавно начал изучать API anypay.io и встрял на самом старте:) При воспроизведении кода:

```
import requests
import hashlib
from data import ANYPAY_API_ID, ANYPAY_API_KEY
import json

sign = hashlib.sha256(f'balance{ANYPAY_API_ID()}{ANYPAY_API_KEY()}'.encode())
responce = requests.get(f"https://anypay.io/api/balance/{ANYPAY_API_ID()}", params=str(sign))
print(responce.json())
```

я получаю ошибку 102:

```
{'error': {'code': '102', 'message': 'Invalid sign'}}
```

Исходя из документации(https://anypay.io/doc/api/errors) я выяснил, что проблема заключается в неверной контрольной подписи, но я уже всю голову сломал и не могу понять, где я допустил ошибку.

Comment: `ANYPAY_API_ID` и `ANYPAY_API_KEY` - это функции?

Comment: Да, всё верно, в них находятся персональные api id и api key

Comment: Вы пробовали обрамить параметры с помощью `[]` как в документации? Или разделять параметры `:` как в [примере](https://anypay.io/doc/sci)

Comment: Я сейчас разбираюсь с  API документацией, а Вы посмотрели пример SCI, в API  про `:` ничего не сказано и там вроде контрольная подпись формируется по разному, могу конечно ошибаться в силу малого опыта

Answer (score 1):

> Формирование подписи производится путем склеивания параметров через
>   ":" и создания контрольной суммы MD5. Склеиваются параметры currency,
>   amount, секретный ключ, merchant_id и pay_id.

и не понятно почему вы используете `sha256`

попробуйте так:

```
sign = hashlib.md5(b'currency:amount:secret_key:merchant_id:pay_id').encode()
print(sign.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Это для SCI, а для API используется `hash('sha256', 'balance[API_ID][API_KEY]')`. ТС пользуется API.

Comment: мой косяк, признаю

Answer (score 1):

Решило проблему:

```
responce = requests.get(f"https://anypay.io/api/balance/{ANYPAY_API_ID()}", params={"sign":sign.hexdigest()})
```